# Is inversion of bounded homeomorphisms continuous with the uniform metric?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider the metric space $H$ of uniformly continuous homeomorphisms (with uniformly continuous inverses) of some open bounded subset $G$ of $\mathbb C$, with the uniform metric
$$d(f, g) = \sup_{z \in G} \left|f(z) - g(z)\right|.$$
It is clear that $(f, g) \mapsto f \circ g$ is a continuous map $H \times H \to H$ (and in fact this is due to the uniform metric, not the uniform continuity of any particular homeomorphism), but is inversion $f \mapsto f^{-1}$ a continuous map $H \to H$?

In other words, is it the case that whenever $(f_n) \to f$ uniformly on $G$, where $f$ and each $f_n$ is a uniformly continuous homeomorphism of $G$ with a uniformly continuous inverse, then $(f_n^{-1}) \to f^{-1}$ uniformly on $G$?

Comment: where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm trying to show that $(f_n^{-1} \circ f) \to id$ uniformly, which is equivalent. I expect this to be true since $(f_n) \to f$ uniformly, but I am having trouble putting this "additive" structure into use to prove the "multiplicative" structure that $f_n^{-1} \circ f$ becomes closer and closer to the identity.

Comment: IIRC this is not the case and the reason we usually take the metric $D(f,g) = d(f,g) + d(f^{-1}, g^{-1})$ using your $d$.

Comment: I understand it is not usually the case, but in my question the space $G$ is bounded, which I hope may allow inversion to be continuous. Perhaps it still is not, though.

Comment: Possibly of interest: https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jfs/2013/894108/

Comment: @HennoBrandsma thanks, I will take a look. At first glance it seems quite complicated, but I will try to read it more thoroughly.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen you're right. When I wrote the question I was actually thinking of holomorphic functions, not just homeomorphisms -- and they're automatically uniformly continuous. I'll edit the question to add the assumption of uniform continuity.

Comment: If you require uniform continuity, and still want a group structure, you actually get the uniform isomorphism group. That however is isomorphic to the uniform isomorphism group of the completion of the space. In your case, the completion is compact, so the problem is reduced to homeomorphism groups of compact metric spaces.

Comment: Correction: The uniform isomorphism group of a space is in general of course merely isomorphic to a subgroup of the isomorphism group of the completion.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen do you have a reference for the statement that the uniform isomorphism group of a space is a subgroup of the isomorphism group of the completion?

Comment: I don't have a reference for this specific fact. That there is an algebraic homomorphism follows from the fact that the completion of a metric space is a reflection arrow from the category of metric spaces with uniformly continuous maps to the full subcategory of complete metric spaces. It is not hard to see (from the density of a space in its completion) that this homomorphism is an isometry w.r.t. $d$, which implies that it must be a monomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact $(H, \circ, d)$ will be a topological group whenever $(X, \rho)$
is a bounded metric space. (not necessarily totally bounded)

It is easy to see that 
$d(f \circ g, \operatorname{id}) \le d(f, \operatorname{id}) + d(g, \operatorname{id})$,
 hence composition is continuous at the identity.

Furthermore, it follows immediately from the surjectivity of $h$ that
$d(f \circ h, g \circ h) = d(f, g)$, hence $d$ is right-invariant, so
right translations are clearly continuous.

To show that $H$ is a topological group, it will suffice then to show that
inversion is continuous.

To do this we take arbitrary $f \in H$ and $\epsilon > 0$. By the
uniform continuity of $f^{-1}$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that
$\rho(f^{-1}(x), f^{-1}(y)) < \epsilon$ whenever $\rho(x, y) < \delta$.
For any $g \in H$ such that $d(g, f) < \delta$, we have 
$$\rho(f^{-1}(g(x)), x) = \rho(f^{-1}(g(x)), f^{-1}(f(x))) < \epsilon/2$$ for all $x$, therefore $d(f^{-1} \circ g, \operatorname{id}) \le \epsilon/2 < \epsilon$.
From the right-invariance of $d$ it follows that $$
d(f^{-1} \circ g, \operatorname{id}) = 
d(f^{-1} \circ g, g^{-1} \circ g) = 
d(f^{-1}, g^{-1}) 
$$
so we have $d(f^{-1}, g^{-1}) < \epsilon$, which shows that $f\mapsto f^{-1}$ is continuous.

---

**Additional note:**
Without the assumption of uniform continuity, left translations may fail
to be continuous, in which case inversion can not be continuous either.
As an example take $X = (0,1)^2$ with $f(x,y) = (x^y, y)$ and
$$
g_t(x, y) = \cases{ (2^tx, y) &when $x \le 4^{-t}$ \\
                    ((x-1)/(2^{-t} +1) &otherwise.
}
$$
Here $d(g_t, \operatorname{id}) = 2^{-t} - 4^{-t} < 2^-t$, so $g_t \to \operatorname{id}$ as $t \to \infty$.

On the other hand, taking $x = 4^{-t}, y = 1/t$, we can see
that $d(f\circ g_t, f) \ge 2^{-1} - 4^{-1} \ge 1/4$,
so $f\circ g_t$ does not converge uniformly to $f$, which shows that the left translation by $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: You gave a clear "no, inversion is not continuous" answer, so I am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $K$ be a compact metric space, $H_K$ is the group of self-homeomorphisms $K\to K$ equipped with the topology of uniform convergence. I will prove that the inversion is continuous on $H_K$. If this were not the case, there would exist an (equicontinuous) sequence of homeomorphisms $h_n\to h$ such that $(h_n^{-1})$ does not converge to $h^{-1}$.  By compactness, this means that (after passing to a subsequence in $(h_n)$) there exists $x\in K$, a sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $x$, while $h_n^{-1}(x_n)=y_n$ converges to $y\ne h^{-1}(x)$. Applying $h_n$ and $h$ and taking into account that $h_n\to h$, we obtain that $x_n=h_n(y_n)\to h(y)\ne x$. This contradicts the assumption that $x_n\to x$. qed

Now, apply this to the closure $K$ of your open and bounded subset $G\subset {\mathbb C}$.

Edit: Suppose that $f_n: K\to K$ is a sequence of continuous maps. What does it mean that $f_n$ **does not** converge to $f: K\to K$ (a continuous map) in uniform toplogy? This means (just by negating the definition of uniform convergence) that there exist $r>0$ such that for arbitrarily large $n$, there exist $x_n\in K$ such that $d(f_n(x_n), f(x_n))> r$. Now, by compactness, after extraction, we obtain $x_n\to x$, $f_n(x_n)\to y$ and $y$ has to be different from $f(x)$ since $d(y, f(x))\ge r$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow the important steps: the "by compactness" part and "we obtain that $x_n \to h(y) \neq x$. Could you please elaborate on these steps, the compactness consequence in particular? Thanks!

Comment: I think I see now. I didn't notice that you were using compactness to get _two_ convergent sequences ($(x_n)$ and $(h_n^{-1}(x_n))$), so I was confused about how you knew that $(h_n^{-1}(x_n))$ actually converged. I understand now that you are really using compactness of $K^2$ to get a subsequence of the zippered sequence $(x_n, h_n^{-1}(x_n))$ in $K^2$, which is what you need.

Comment: @feralin: Right.

Comment: Moishe, sorry, I also don't see how to apply your answer to homeomorphisms of $G$. You say to apply the fact that inversion is continuous on self-homeomorphisms of $\bar G$ (equipped with uniform convergence topology) to deduce that inversion is continuous on self-homeomorphisms of $G$, also with the uniform convergence topology, but I don't see how to do this. Could you clarify please?

Comment: I've tried to prove that deduction, but I keep running into the problem that a homeomorphism of $G$ need not extend continuously to a homeomorphism of $\bar G$.

Comment: I think I'll just ask as a separate MSE question.

Comment: @feralin: They do not in general, but you assume uniform continuity of inverses and that suffices: If $g=f^{-1}$ for $f: G\to G$, then the continuous extension of $g$ to $cl(G)$ is the inverse of the continuous extension of $f$ (since this is so on a dense subset).

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! I forgot about the uniform continuity. (Perhaps I shouldn't have added it in the first place -- my motivation is about holomorphic functions, and I mistakenly thought that they were uniformly continuous. In fact they do not have to be...)