# Is inversion a continuous function in a space of homeomorphisms?

Tags: general-topology, uniform-convergence

This is a continuation of [this question about continuity of inversion with the topology of uniform convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2269145/is-inversion-of-bounded-homeomorphisms-continuous-with-the-uniform-metric).

For $M$ a bounded metric space, let $H_M$ be the space of homeomorphisms of $M$ with the supremum metric
$$d_{H_M}(f, g) = \sup_{x \in K} d_M(f(x), g(x)).$$

Now let $S$ be a dense subset of a compact metric space $K$, and suppose we know that inversion $f \mapsto f^{-1}$ is a continuous function $H_K \to H_K$.

**Question:** Does it follow that inversion is a continuous function $H_S \to H_S$?

I keep getting stuck trying to prove this since it is not guaranteed that a homeomorphism of $S$ continuously extends to a homeomorphism of $K$.

Suppose that every homeomorphism $f$ of $S$ *does* continuously extend to a homeomorphism $\tilde f$ of $K$. If $(f_n) \to f$ is a convergent sequence in $H_S$, then $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ as functions $S \to S$, so then $(\tilde{f_n}) \to \tilde f$ uniformly as functions $K \to K$, so $(\tilde{f_n})$ converges to $\tilde f$ in $H_K$, so since inversion is continuous in $H_K$ we then have $(\tilde{f_n}^{-1})$ converging to ${\tilde f}^{-1}$ in $H_K$, so $(f_n^{-1})$ converges to $f^{-1}$ in $H_S$ by restriction to $S$. Of course this proof depends on the extensions of homeomorphisms from $S$ to $K$.

Comment: No, it is not continuous in this case.

Comment: A member of $H_S$ will not generally extend to a member of $H_K.$..... E.g. $K=[\pi, 3\pi]$ and $S=K\cap \mathbb Q$. Let $f(x) \in H_S$ where $f$ maps $(\pi,2\pi)\cap S$ onto $(2\pi,3\pi)\cap S,$ such that  $f$ restricted to $(\pi,2\pi)\cap K$ is increasing, and $f$ restricted to $(2\pi,3\pi)\cap S$ is decreasing. Any extension of $f$ to the domain $K$ would not be monotonic and hence would not a member of $H_K.$

Comment: Inversion is continuous on $H_K.$ My proof repeatedly uses the property that any sequence in $K$ has a convergent sub-sequence. So I have doubts that inversion  is necessarily continuous on $H_S$ when $S$ is a dense proper subset of $K$ and hence not a compact subspace of $K$.

Comment: In my first comment, "$f$ restricted to $(\pi,2\pi)\cap K$" should be "$f$ restricted to $(\pi,2\pi)\cap S$".